# How to execute multiple SQL statements in virtualmin / mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sql

Using the "Execute SQL" feature of the mysql addin for virtualmin, what is the syntax for executing multiple statements? For example if I want to do:

```
delete from Table1;
delete from Table2;
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to execute SQL : SQL delete from Table1; delete from Table2; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete from Table2' at line 1

Comment: I assume this works successfully if you only supply a single statement?

Comment: yes, it works fine on single statements. I suspect there's just some tricky syntax for multiple, batch-style, statements.

Answer (score 1):

Save your statements to a .sql file and select "Run SQL from file", you will be prompted to upload the SQL file.